# 'Tripwire' sound design

Tags: sound-effects, gameaudio

I really stuck with making 'tripwire' break sound for game a I'm working on. Does anyone have idea where to go with that sound of that tight thin line being break by someone walking through.

For now I just got some simple short trigger sound/mechanics after but rly have no clue where to go with other. Probably a bit of rope stretch for the beginning.

Would be really thankfull for any advices.

Answer (score 3):

If the wire is to actually break, I'd go for a guitar string; a thin one, maybe an 8.

Tie it off to something either resonant or not, depending on whether your scenario is indoors or out, then just pull it with one finger til it breaks - wear a glove or it'll hurt your finger ;)

If it isn't to break, just twang, then you save the cost of more guitar strings if your levels aren't correct the first time.

I wouldn't use a guitar as your resonant tie-off in either case, or it will sound just like a guitar, not a tripwire.

Comment: +1. Just wanted to add that a solid body guitar would work if its not being amplified. But I'd use a throwaway. The ease with using the guitar is that you can adjust the tension of the string - and possibly get different tonalities as well. Choose the most appropriate one later.